# Android Emulator RAM size results in error

Tags: android, android-emulator

As I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator) Post in stackoverflow I tried to Increase RAM size of my device But it results in

```
Emulator encounters a problem needs to close
```

I tried wipe user data

```
My device RAM size specified:1024MB 
My PC RAM is 4GB.
```

Why this happening? Is any other way to increase emulator speed?

Answer (score 1):

In Android Virtual device manager, where you edit your device, specify ram size and don't forget to add unit e.g. MB, Kb etc. otherwise it will crash like that.  Example:
1024MB